# Fail restore a SQL Server database .BAK from Enterprise to Express (Error 909)

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, sql-server-2014-express

I need help. I recently download a sample SQL Server database from the internet (link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18279).

When I tried to restore that database to my computer, the process was failed because my SQL Server is not in the same version with the database came from.
I currently using SQL Server 2014 Express Edition, and the data that I've download was from Enterprise Edition, so some of the features is not available in my current edition.

What should I do to restore that database successfully without installing the Enterprise Edition?
I need a sample of huge database (with millions of rows or more) for educational purpose, and I think this is the proper one.
Or maybe any of you can give me the similar database that compatible with Express Edition.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore as long as the database doesn't have  enterprise features and it doesn't exceed max size of express edition.You also have to ensure both are of same version  .This can be checked by using

```
select @@version
```

if none of the above helps,you can generate scripts and run them